# Key order while writing a JSON object in Python

Tags: python, json

I need to show an output like below as a result of a webservice call

```
{
  "predictions": [
    {
      "id": 18009,
      "cuisine": "italian",
      "probability": 0.17846838753494407
    },
    {
      "id": 28583,
      "cuisine": "italian",
      "probability": 0.1918703125538735
    }
  ]
}
```

I have the below code to create the object:

```
    json_data = []
    for i in range (0, len(predicted_labels)):
        data = {}
        data['id'] = int(test['id'][i])
        data['cuisine'] = categoricalTransformer[predicted_labels[i]]
        item = predicted_probability[i]
        data['probability'] = item[predicted_labels[i]]
        json_data.append(data)
    json_return = {"predictions":json_data}
    return jsonify(json_return)
```

which reorders the key alphabetically as shown below.

```
{
  "predictions": [
    {
      "cuisine": "italian",
      "id": 18009,
      "probability": 0.17846838753494407
    },
    {
      "cuisine": "italian",
      "id": 28583,
      "probability": 0.1918703125538735
    }
  ]
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: There is no key order in a Json object.

Comment: Why is the key order relevant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rebuild your new dictionary with a [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), and append ordered dictionaries with a [`collections.OrderedDict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from collections import defaultdict
from json import dumps

data = {
    "predictions": [
        {"id": 18009, "cuisine": "italian", "probability": 0.17846838753494407},
        {"id": 28583, "cuisine": "italian", "probability": 0.1918703125538735},
    ]
}

key_order = ["id", "cuisine", "probability"]

result = defaultdict(list)
for dic in data["predictions"]:
    ordered = OrderedDict((key, dic.get(key)) for key in key_order)
    result["predictions"].append(ordered)

print(dumps(result))
# {"predictions": [{"id": 18009, "cuisine": "italian", "probability": 0.17846838753494407}, {"id": 28583, "cuisine": "italian", "probability": 0.1918703125538735}]}
```

[`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) here serializes the dictionary into a JSON formatted string.

**Note:** If you are using **Python3.6+**, you can use normal dictionaries instead of `OrderedDict()`, since insertion order of keys is remembered. However, in 3.6 it is an implementation feature, whereas in 3.7 it is a language feature. You read more about this at [Are dictionaries ordered in Python 3.6+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6/39980744#39980744).

You can probably rely on this feature for applications that have a minimum requirement of Python3.6. Furthermore, its probably safer to user `OrderedDict()` anyways, so your code can be backwards compatible for all python versions.

Comment: Although you are correct that Python 3.6+  remembers insertion order, this behaviour is a side-effect of an implementation change and should not be relied on. For more future-proof code and greater reusability, `OrderedDict` should be used.

Comment: @Grismar Yes thats a very good point, cheers.

Comment: @Grismar This is correct for 3.6 only. Since Python 3.7 it is a documented feature. Still backward compatibility should be considered.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into [Ordered Dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). It remembers the insertion order, and you would be able to organise your json via this collection this way.

Example:

```
datadict = {'a':'a', 'c':'c', 'b':'b'}
import collections

print (collections.OrderedDict(datadict))
#OrderedDict([('a':'a'), ('c':'c'), ('b':'b')])

x = collections.OrderedDict(datadict)
print (dict(x))
#{'a':'a', 'c':'c', 'b':'b'}

print (x == datadict)
#True


print (collections.OrderedDict(sorted(datadict.items(), key=lambda t:t[0])))
#OrderedDict([('a':'a'), ('b':'b'), ('c':'c')])

z = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(datadict.items(), key=lambda t:t[0]))
print (dict(z))
#{'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':'c'}

print (z == datadict)
#True
```

Using this, you can convert your `json_return` dict object into an `OrderedDict` with your desired insertion order and then return that `OrderedDict` object or convert it back into a `dict` and return that dict